# how to upload csv file with date column in Apache superset in same format?

Tags: apache-superset

Hi I have CSV file with data column and I want to upload it into the apache superset database. However, When I upload the file date column is formatted by  the superset automatically and some dates( when the first two numbers are less than 12) are changed.

```
admission_date
19/02/2022
04/01/2022
04/01/2022
22/02/2022
14/02/2022
```

after uploaded it automatically rearrange the date format to something like this

```
 admission_date
19/02/2022
01/04/2022
01/04/2022
22/02/2022
14/02/2022
```

it has changed the date 04/01/2022 to 01/04/2022
how can I prevent this?